# MEDIA_ERR_DECODE on HTML5 video in iOS UIWebView after many plays

Tags: ios, objective-c, html, video, uiwebview

After playing around 20 short video clips (mp4's) in an HTML5 video control in a UIWebView in iOS, subsequent clips are failing with a `MEDIA_ERR_DECODE`.  The thing is, is that I **know** the videos are fine, because they were previously played, sometimes even during the same session.

Furthermore, if you wait long enough to request a new video clip, it will usually start working again.

I also know it's not the server because I can do the exact same operation on chrome on my desktop computer and it always works.

Based on my troubleshooting, it seems like the bug is in iOS itself.

1. Does anyone have any ideas for working around this?
2. Is there any way to get more information about an media decode error like this in iOS?  I tried using Safari's development tool to listen to the http requests but I can't let it record longer than a few seconds before it hits an out of memory error and kills the app.

**UPDATE:  It also works fine when run in the iOS simulator.  It seems the problem only occurs on the iPad itself**

Comment: I have also seen this on iOS 8.1.3 but with all video resources local to the app.

Comment: just posted an answer to my original question.  hope it helps you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After a discussion with Apple Support, the problem has been fixed.  The problem has to do with the hardware H264 decoder.  Basically, I was never removing the videos from the hardware decoder buffer by never releasing the video resources (which I thought javascript would do itself).

So I was setting the source like this:

```
$(vid).src = "some source file";
$(vid).play();
... some other stuff happens ...
$(vid).remove();
```

Doing it this way never removed the video from the decoder buffer, which meant that eventually it not be able to decode any more videos.

To fix this, this is how you must remove the video from the DOM:

```
$(vid).src = "some source file";
$(vid).play();
... some other stuff happens ...
$(vid).remove();
$(vid).src = "";
$(vid).load();
```

Now I realize that this doesn't make a ton of sense because after `.remove()` is called, I would have assumed that the control has been removed from the DOM and any garbage collection would do the rest automatically.  However, it doesn't work like that.  I hope this helps other people.

Comment: I had the same problem, and this REALLY helps! Thank you.

Comment: Thank you soooooo much I have been trying to get to the bottom of this for months now, gave up a couple of times along the way... It's like apple to have some obscure obstruction that throws no helpful errors.
P.S. This method extends to react, check this thread out for reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51499951/react-video-re-rendering-issue-in-ios

Comment: looks like the problem even extends to current desktop safaris, however it seems to not occur that often. any chance you could tell us what the content of the discussion with apple support was?

Answer (score 0):

It is not iOS specific. I can reproduce in Chrome web browser.

NB : If the video has multiple sources, you must reset src attribute for each source.

```
var sources = $(vid).getElementsByTagName('source');
for (var index = 0; index < sources.length; index++)
{
    sources[index].src = "";
}
$(vid).load();
```

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to raise your content quality up

Answer (score 0):

jugg1es answer above is correct, but the problem still exists if you're trying to use HLS video. When I tried to use his solution with jquery-3.1.1.js I hit an error in jquery's load() method.  Not using jquery actually worked for me:

```
    document.getElementById(id).src = "";
    document.getElementById(id).load();
```

Thanks jugg1es you saved my project.