# HTML5 video MEDIA_ERR_DECODE occurs randomly

Tags: javascript, html, video, decode, opera

I'm developing the project witch contains 6 audio and video elements which plays one after another.
The code order before issue is like that:

1. preloading all media resources till "canplaythrough"
2. playing video-1
3. stoping video-1 and playing audio-1
4. stoping audio-1 and playing video-1 again.

Then the video-1 is playing 2-3 seconds and stops sending the error code 3 (3 = MEDIA_ERR_DECODE - error occurred when decoding). I have tried to play the same video just by link and it is playing fine.

Also the problem randomly occurs on some OS in some browsers.
For example:

- Win10 latest Opera - occurs
- Win10 latest Chrome - fine
- MacOS all browsers - fine
- Another MacOS latest Chrome - occurs in 1 of 10 cases
- IPhone all browsers - fine
- IPad all browsers - fine

**UPDATE** It is occuring on Win10 latest Opera only during first view or if cache is disabled.

**UPDATE 2** Video Codec is H.264, Audio Codec is AAC, Framerate is 24.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Definitions for MEDIA_ERR_DECODE

[HTML5 spec for for media error codes](http://w3c.github.io/html/semantics-embedded-content.html#error-codes)

> An error of some description occurred while decoding the media resource, after the resource was established to be usable.

[Mozilla MediaError documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaError)

> Despite having previously been determined to be usable, an error occurred while trying to decode the media resource, resulting in an error.

Firefox error message (as in this [support ticket](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1058608))

> The video playback was aborted due to a corruption problem or because the video used features your browser did not support.

## Common reasons for firing

- The video is encrypted, but you failed to decrypt it. This can be due to various reasons:

  **1)** Encrypting a video with multiple DRM schemes (rather than just one) can cause decryption to fail on some browsers;

  **2)** You neglected to decrypt the video before it started playing (perhaps it's accidentally set to auto-play before you've completed the license request);

  **3)** There are insufficient resources to decode the video because several video buffers (even if they're not encrypted videos) have been used up already.
- Your browser doesn't support the particular media format (eg. DASH). This may be remediable with a plugin, depending on the media type.
- You have set the wrong MIME type on your `<source>` element; note that certain browsers prefer different MIME types to be declared in order to decode certain video formats.
- Too many video buffers have been used up without being cleared.

## Diagnosis in your case

As the error fires fairly indeterminately, it seems like a resources issue rather than any of the other possibilities. You have six audio and video elements playing one-after-another, so you should clear each one out each time they have delivered their media. You should also not load all six side-by-side.

```
var video = document.getElementById('myVideo');
var nextVideo = document.getElementById('nextVideo');

video.addEventListener('ended', (event)=>{
    video.src = ""; // or the src attribute of the active <source> element.
    video.load();
    // If you aren't going to re-use this video element, you should also
    // remove all eventListeners from it and then remove it from the DOM.
    nextVideo.preload = "auto"; // I'm assuming the src has already been set.
    nextVideo.autoplay = true;
    // Second video should start playing now due to autoplay. If not, call load() again.
});

video.preload = "auto";
nextVideo.preload = "metadata";
video.src = "video.mp4";
nextVideo.src = "nextVideo.mp4";
video.autoplay = true;
nextVideo.load(); // I believe load() might not be necessary for preload = "metadata".
video.load(); // I believe load() is necessary for preload = "auto".
// First video should start playing now due to autoplay.
```

It's a similar case to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30105846/5951226) related to iOS.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was because I was streaming high bitrate HLS content, and not limiting how much to buffer.

The SourceBuffer was full and `appendBuffer` failed, but in Chrome (Chrome 91), the error message was a misleading `MEDIA_ERR_DECODE`.

This can happen rather quickly, start the video at a certain timestamp, play it for 30 seconds and `MEDIA_ERR_DECODE` error will reliably happen, and it seems to happen reliably at a certain video timestamp, which led me to believe it was indeed due to some problem in the video encoding.

But it was not. A professional from my VOD hosting platform suggested that I limit the buffer length, by changing (I'm using hls.js) [maxMaxBufferLength](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/blob/master/docs/API.md#maxmaxbufferlength) from the default 600s to 30s, the problem was solved! `MEDIA_ERR_DECODE` never happened again after I made this change.

Answer (score 0):

When the video file size is too large, you may encounter this problem. Recommended setting to：

```
video.preload = "auto"
```

Change to:

```
video.preload = "metadata"
```