# Chromium - Media source extension - Append: stream parsing failed

Tags: google-chrome, video-streaming, chromium, media-source

Using Media source extension (MSE), I am trying to play an mp4 stream on web browser.
On firefox it's ok.
On chromium based web browser (Opera, Chrome and Edge), it's not.
I have the error :

> Append: stream parsing failed. Data size=689 append_window_start=0 append_window_end=inf

My javascript receive fragments of the mp4 file and append them to MSE.
Appending the first fragment of my mp4 containing the ftyp box atom, works fine.
But appending second fragment containing the moov atom give me the error and then close the media source.

I didn't find out what's wrong on the moov atom. Did someone see what's going on with this moov atom?

Here is a screenshot of the hexa of [the second fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EB6sP.png) (containing moov atom) I send and there of the [Chrome Media Internals log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2W9a.png)

Concatenating all 327 fragments give me a readable mp4 file readable with VLC, html video tag,...

I have tried reading the mp4 directly as file in vidéo tag in chromium, it works.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm hitting the exact same issue.

Comment: After making a Chromium debug build and stepping through the decoding code, it turns out Chrome needs the fragments to contain a `tfdt` box.

Comment: @Hans can you please elaborate? I'm having exactly the same problem.. CHUNK_DEMUXER_ERROR_APPEND_FAILED. Works on other browsers, only fails in MacOS Chrome. How did you fix it? much appreciated

Comment: @Kevin I fixed it by making sure each subsequent fragment contains the `tfdt` box. While, as far as I remember, that box is not required by the MP4 spec, chrome does seem to require it.

To debug, I would recommend:
1. Concat the chunks and run a MP4 validator on it.
2. If the above doesn't help you, use a MP4 box dumper to see how your fragments look like. It should contain the `tfdt` box in the media fragments. You can also compare this to what is required by the spec.

Comment: @Hans thanks very much for sharing! It turned out that my fragments were fine, my problem was that the bitrate was quite high and I didn't limit the max buffer time. Chrome buffered so many fragments that the SourceBuffer kind of ran out, and appendBuffer throw and error. (I still think `MEDIA_ERR_DECODE` / `CHUNK_DEMUXER_ERROR_APPEND_FAILED` is quite misleading). I explained it in detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68176963/6247478 . Anyway, this is indeed a difficult problem to troubleshoot, glad we both figured it out. Thanks for sharing!