# Source Buffer Append: stream parsing failed

Tags: javascript, html5-video, media-source

Similar to a few questions like this [Chromium - Media source extension - Append: stream parsing failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63156324/chromium-media-source-extension-append-stream-parsing-failed)

I'm trying to play a WebM file on Chrome using the Media Source Extensions, but no answers are working for me.

This is the error in the Media tab
[image: Error message stating "Append: stream parsing failed. Data size=131072\nappend_window_start=0 append_window_end=inf"]

```
mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/webm; codecs="vp9"')
sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(data)
```

Has this to do with the video file encoding?

Comment: Highly probable yes, could you host this file somewhere public for inspection? Also might be worth showing the full code rather than just these two lines.

Answer (score 1):

The video file had no audio track. Switched to a file with Audio and it worked. Will solve silent video later.