# Video player corruption in social media video list

Tags: javascript, angular, html, ionic-framework

I am attempting to create an app that has social media features like Instagram, Twitter, etc where you can post videos and watch them in a list. However, when the list reaches a certain point, all the videos end up loading 'corrupted'. (Only shows a play icon with a slash through it)

The problem only occurs on iOS. I have done a little research and it seems to stem from this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28905253/media-err-decode-on-html5-video-in-ios-uiwebview-after-many-plays).

I think that is the cause of my issue because if I use the solution from that thread and reload the page, the videos load fine once again.

However, I want this list to be as long as the user keeps scrolling. So if iOS has a limit on the number of videos that can be loaded at one time then how is one to accomplish making an infinite scroll?

Thanks,

Troy

Comment: Do you really have to *load* all these videos? Can't you simply show placeholders, filled with a static image, and only on click of this image would you create the video element and load it?

Comment: That's what I was thinking would be the only solution. But what happens when the video is scrolled out of view? Should it then be removed and re-added conditionally? The videos are auto-played when scrolled into view.

Comment: As a current and maybe temporary solution I set the source of the video while it is in view and when it leaves the view I set a timer to remove the source. I'm not sure if this is bad practice? It seems like it could potentially be more costly.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of loading videos stream them. It would save memory.
When video is out of view, pause the stream to keep bandwidth and save traffic.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it. I am using Firebase storage to hold my videos so I am not very sure how to go about it or what the differences are between using a url-link in a `<video>` tag and streaming are.